# How to implement jquery date time picker with zend framework 2 using zf FORM

Tags: zend-framework, zend-framework2, jquerydatetimepicker

Thanks in advance, 
Want to implement jquery date time picker with zend framework 2 using ZF FORM, with validation of form date selection depending on to date.

Please suggest the best practice.

Answer (score 1):

You can proceed as follows

In your form you add a date field:

```
$this->add([
    'name' => 'birthDate',
    'type' => 'Zend\Form\Element\Date',
    'attributes' => [
        'id' => 'birthDate',
        'class' => 'required datepicker-date',
        'type' => 'text'
    ],
    'options' => [
        'label' => 'Birth date'
    ]
]);
```

notice the `'type' => 'text'`.

Then in the view you print the form element as you please and add the following javascript snippet:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $( ".datepicker-date" ).datepicker({
        dateFormat: "dd-mm-yy",
        changeMonth: true,
        changeYear: true
    });
});
```

Adjust the options according to your needs.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it by using `bootstrap-datepicker`

So firstly you want to insert following `CSS and JS` files.Those are

```
1.bootstrap.css
2.bootstrap-datetimepicker.min.css
3.jquery.min.js
4.bootstrap-datepicker.min.js

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('#yourTextFieldIDName').datepicker({
            format: "yyyy-mm-dd",
            viewMode: "day",
            minViewMode: 'day'
        });
</script>
```